# Broccoli asset rev fingerprint urls in json file

Tags: ember-cli

My rails app and `index.html` file are hosted on heroku and the rest of the assets are on s3, there's a `manifest.json` file that is required in order to enable mobile web app mode for chrome on android that looks like:

```
{
  "short_name": "Kinlan's Amaze App",
  "name": "Kinlan's Amazing Application ++",
  "icons": [
    {
      "src": "launcher-icon-2x.png",
      "sizes": "96x96",
      "type": "image/png"
    },
    {
      "src": "launcher-icon-3x.png",
      "sizes": "144x144",
      "type": "image/png"
    },
    {
      "src": "launcher-icon-4x.png",
      "sizes": "192x192",
      "type": "image/png"
    }
  ],
  "start_url": "/index.html",
  "display": "standalone",
  "orientation": "landscape"
}
```

In my `brocfile.js` I have included the `json` extension to the list of fingerprintable files.

The actual file gets fingerprinted but the contents such as `"src": "launcher-icon-3x.png"` do not.

Anyway to do this or do I need to make an in-Repo addon to handle the creation of the file?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

After looking through the [source](https://github.com/rickharrison/broccoli-asset-rev/blob/0c02448f6189af677260280d4f965113b82e0a5f/index.js#L13) the following can be done by adding `json` to the replaceExtensions option:

```
var app = new EmberApp({
  fingerprint: {
    prepend: fingerprint,
    extensions: ['js', 'css', 'png', 'jpg', 'gif', 'svg', 'json'],
    replaceExtensions: ['html', 'css', 'js', 'json']
  }
});
```